# Rendering out new line properly in openpyxl generated XLSX file

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm using `openpyxl` to open an .xlsx file, update some values in it and save it as a different .xlsx file. I am trying to add a footer with new lines in it:

```
# example code
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
sheet.header_footer.left_footer.font_size = 7
sheet.header_footer.left_footer.text = '&BSome text&B\nMore text\nEven more'
sheet.header_footer.right_footer.font_size = 7
sheet.header_footer.right_footer.text = 'Page &P of &N'
wb.save('new_file.xlsx')
```

But when I open newly created file and look at the footer, `\n` gets replaced in a weird way:

```
Some text^lMore text^pEven more
```

I have also noticed that if I try to convert it to PDF with a help of libreoffice, e.g. like this:

```
os.system('libreoffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf --outdir /path/on/disk new_file.xlsx')
```

the generated PDF renders it out to something different again:

```
Some text_x000D_More text_x000D_Even more
```

How can I properly generate new line in the footer?
<sub>(Might be worth of mentioning that I'm using openpyxl 2.3.3 with Python 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04. Version of LibreOffice is 5.0.5.2)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel's headers and footers use a weird control code format where `\n` is replaced by *x000D* in XML. The footer is correct but LibreOffice is not rendering it correctly.

Comment: Ah, true that. I managed to find Microsoft Excel on Windows machine and it does render out properly there. I know that this is a bit different question then, but is there some suggested workaround for this issue?

Comment: Did you ever file a but report about this? I cannot believe this is already 4 years old and nothing happened.. :-)

Comment: After correcting the file and comparing the xml, it appears &#10; is added as a newline.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is still relevant in 2020 and it has nothing to do with libreoffice. Rather, it has to do with the way openpyxl escapes text. Which works fine I suppose, however on header and footer the line break seems to be unescaped (at least in an example file I was given which was created in excel). Unless a fix is released, you can do the following monkey patching:

```
from openpyxl.worksheet.header_footer import HeaderFooterItem                

def unescape_newline(self):
    original_value = self.__str_orig__()
    return original_value.replace("_x000a_", "\n")

# please note: the following sentinel is very important.
# without it, you'll hit recursion error as you cannot simply
# replace __str__ over and over.
if not hasattr(HeaderFooterItem, "__str_orig__"):
    HeaderFooterItem.__str_orig__ = HeaderFooterItem.__str__
    HeaderFooterItem.__str__ = unescape_newline

# now you can assign newlines like so:
sheet.oddFooter.center.text = "This\nis\nmulti\nline\footer"
```